How to remove Word content?
Can anyone tell me how to delete paragraphs and tables in Word? I looked for this in the python docx documentation, but it provides more information on adding content. I am attempting to address the task by displaying snippets, but the file that was supposed to be modified remains unchanged.
def modificar_docx(text_to_replace_list, text_to_replace_with_list,mode):
    doc = Document(doct)
    replacement_index = 0
    paragraphs_to_remove = []
    for i,paragraph in enumerate(doc.paragraphs):
        for run in paragraph.runs:
            if not mode and text_to_replace_with_list[5] == "Prime" and run.text == "Potencia Standby":
                paragraphs_to_remove.append(i)
            elif not mode and text_to_replace_with_list[5] == "Standby" and run.text == "Potencia Prime":
                paragraphs_to_remove.append(i)
            if "/-" in run.text:
                run.text = run.text.replace("/-", "")       
                
    for i in reversed(paragraphs_to_remove):
        p = doc.paragraphs[i]._element
        p.getparent().remove(p) 
    
    doc.save(docn)

for table in doc.tables[:]:
    element = table._element 
    element.getparent().remove(element)
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        mode = int(sys.argv[1])
        chunksA, chunksB = read_data(mode)
        if mode:
            chunksA = [chunksA[0],chunksA[4],chunksA[6],chunksA[7],chunksA[8],chunksA[9],chunksA[4],chunksA[1],chunksA[6],
                       chunksA[7],chunksA[8],chunksA[9],chunksA[10],chunksA[11],chunksA[12],chunksA[13],chunksA[14],chunksA[15],
                       chunksA[16],chunksA[17],chunksA[18],chunksA[19],chunksA[20],chunksA[25],chunksA[26],chunksA[27],chunksA[28],
                       chunksA[29],chunksA[30],chunksA[31],chunksA[32],chunksA[3],chunksA[21],chunksA[22],chunksA[23],chunksA[24]]
            data_to_replace = ["XX • XX • XX"]*2 + ["XX • XX"] + ["XX"]*5 + ["-"]*25+ ["..."]+["-"]*4
            cells_to_replace = ["+"]*32
            text_to_replace_with = chunksA
            table_to_replace_with = chunksB
            modificar_docx(data_to_replace,text_to_replace_with,mode)
            #modificar_tablas()
        else:
            chunksA = [chunksA[8],chunksA[2],chunksA[9],chunksA[11],chunksA[12],chunksA[9],chunksA[0],chunksA[11],chunksA[12],
                       chunksA[13],chunksA[14],chunksA[15],chunksA[16],chunksA[17],chunksA[18],chunksA[19],chunksA[20],
                       chunksA[22],chunksA[23],chunksA[24],chunksA[25],chunksA[26],chunksA[27],chunksA[3],chunksA[21]]
            doc = Document(doct)
            for table in doc.tables[:]:
                element = table._element 
                element.getparent().remove(element)
            doc.save(docn)
            data_to_replace = ["XX • XX • XX"] + ["XX • XX"] + ["XX"]*3 + ["-"]*19 + ["..."] + ["-"]*2
            text_to_replace_with = chunksA
            modificar_docx(data_to_replace,text_to_replace_with,mode)

`

I have reviewed the necessary sections of the documentation and applied debugging methods.

For a minimal reproducable example you should share a file. Must not be the original, but a file which show the problem.
